# BinaryNode' does not name a type

Tags: c++, function, class, member

I have a class with a struct inside it in the `.h` header:

```
template <typename DataType>

class BST
{
public:
    struct BinaryNode
    {
       // variables
    };
    //functions
private:
    BinaryNode *findMin(BinaryNode *t) const; //done
    BinaryNode *findMax(BinaryNode *t) const; //done
    //other functions and variables
};
```

and when I make the implementation for these functions in the `.cpp`:

```
template <typename DataType>
BinaryNode* BST<DataType>::findMin(BST<DataType>::BinaryNode<DataType> *t)
{
   //do something
}

template <typename DataType>
BinaryNode* BST<DataType>::findMax(BST<DataType>::BinaryNode<DataType> *t)
{
   //do something
}
```

I get the error on `BinaryNode* BST<DataType>::findMax(BST<DataType>::BinaryNode<DataType> *t)` and `findMin` that `BinaryNode does not name a type`

I have tried using the `BinaryNode<Datatype> *` but that too has the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not specifying the type for the return parameter of your functions, and you gave a template parameter to the `BinaryNode` input parameter.

```
template <typename DataType>
class BST
{
public:
    struct BinaryNode
    {
       // variables
    };
    //functions
private:
    BinaryNode *findMin(BinaryNode *t) const; //done
    BinaryNode *findMax(BinaryNode *t) const; //done
    //other functions and variables
};

template <typename DataType>
typename BST<DataType>::BinaryNode* BST<DataType>::findMin(BST<DataType>::BinaryNode *t) const
{
   //do something
}

template <typename DataType>
typename BST<DataType>::BinaryNode* BST<DataType>::findMax(BST<DataType>::BinaryNode *t) const
{
   //do something
}
```

or to shorten the input parameter:

```
template <typename DataType>
typename BST<DataType>::BinaryNode* BST<DataType>::findMax(BinaryNode *t) const
{
   //do something
}
```

Note that the return parameter needs to be specified in full since when the compiler gets there it does not yet know that it's reading a function implementation for the BST class. In addition `typename` is required since `BinaryNode` in that context is a typename that depends on a template, and the compiler cannot know that unless you make it explicit.

Answer (score 0):

The BinaryNode is not in the global namespace.  Also, it is not a templated struct, it's just a struct inside a class that happens to be templated.

So `BST<DataType>::BinaryNode` is what you are looking for *outside* of the body of the templated BST class.  You can simply refer to it as BinaryNode inside of BST if you mean the BinaryNode for the current template expansion.

*(And you have to mention which template parameterization your out-of-body definitions are corresponding to...as @Svalorzen's more complete answer mentions.)*